# SAPUI5 Data Binding get the value changed in change event

Tags: javascript, data-binding, sapui5

I am changing a model on websocket messages. I attached a change event function to it:

```
oBindingModel.attachChange(function(oEvent){}
```

Now, inside the function, I need to know which value has changed. I searched trough the oEvent Object as well as the returned object from calling this insinde the function. There is a mEventRegistry with an array named change, but I can not find the value in there. Is there any possiblity?

[the object returned from this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqRKX.png)

Thanks!

Comment: Which type of model are you using? is it json model?

Comment: I must admit the API is really bad, but don't you know the path of the binding you were attaching to?

Comment: I am using a JSON model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the event handler function, you have access to the `oEvent` object which contains every information about the source of the event.
To access this object, just call `oEvent.getSource()` in your anonymous function body.

This will return with the source object, which holds the whole model and a most important thing - the `path` of the changed property. Just call the `oEvent.getSource().getPath()` to retrieve this information.

Now you know the path, so you can retrieve the value from the model.